# 403 error when using LWP::UserAgent but not with WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, http-status-code-403, www-mechanize, lwp-useragent

I am trying to access a site using Perl5 and LWP::UserAgent. However upon connecting, the script dies with a "403 access denied" message. The weird part is that it works flawlessly using WWW::Mechanize but the fetch code is the exact same.
Normally I'd suspect the user agent being the cause but as mentioned before the code is the same in both cases.

Is there a difference in how WWW::Mechanize and LWP::UserAgent handle requests that could cause this issue?

Here is some sample code that demonstrates two different approaches.

```
# Mechanize
use strict;
use warnings "all";
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(
    agent_alias => 'Mozilla/5.0',
    show_progress => 1);

my $mech->get("www.foo.com");

# LWP
use strict;
use warnings "all";
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(
    agent_alias => 'Mozilla/5.0',
    show_progress => 1);

my $r = $ua->get("www.foo.com");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `agent_alias` argument documented, neither for LWP::UserAgent nor for WWW::Mechanize. And there is also no `agent_alias` argument implement. Instead the *argument gets ignored in both cases* and it *uses the builtin default*. But the *default is different*. There is a `agent_alias` *method* though for WWW::Mechanize. From [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-agent_alias-alias):

> ...For instance,
>
> ```
> $mech->agent_alias( 'Windows IE 6' );
> ```
>
> sets your User-Agent to
>
> ```
> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
> ```

According to the [documentation of LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#CONSTRUCTOR-METHODS) the argument you actually want to use is properly called `agent` and defaults to `libwww-perl/#.###` (the `#.###` being the version number). With WWW::Mechanize the same argument can be used but the documented different default is `WWW-Mechanize/#.##`.

Comment: It would be nice to say that the correct parameter for `new` is called `agent`, and you should say what the default user agent strings are

Comment: @Borodin: you are right. I've added this information  to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It seems odd that a site would return *Forbidden* for `libwww-perl` and not for `WWW-Mechanize`. It must be a hard-coded exclusion, and not a very effective one!

Comment: Looking through my older scripts I seem to have used "agent" in the past but at some point and for unknown reasons I switched to agent_alias. A very shoddy mistake. Apologies for this blunder.